# Quais são as principais vantagens de se utilizar o recurso de modularização do Java 9+?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, jigsaw

A partir do Java 9 temos a possibilidade de modularizar nossa aplicação utilizando o chamado **Java Platform Module System**

Antes do Java 9, a modularização era feita puramente através de JARs, onde tinhamos várias bibliotecas, e era possível modularizar a aplicação com vários JARs (por exemplo, criar JARs contendo apenas entidades, contendo utilitários, anotações...)

Desta forma, levanto os seguintes questionamentos:

1. Que ganho expressivo temos ao utilizar o novo sistema de módulos?
2. Em termos de complexidade, o quão fácil é sua aplicabilidade em projetos grandes que já estão rodando em Java 8 por exemplo?
3. Durante atualização de bibliotecas, volta e meia nos deparamos com conflitos entre versões e dependências. Nesse cenário de modularização, este problema não se torna mais comum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Que ganho expressivo temos ao utilizar o novo sistema de módulos?

Aqui, pelo que pude ler e sentir o sabor (não pude sorver um grande gole, apenas uma provinha na ponta da língua) do Jigsaw, são duas as principais vantagens:

1. você pode criar classes que não irá expor e usar em *qualquer* pacote do seu módulo
2. otimização da busca da classe pelo `classpath`

A primeira parte inclusive eu senti quando se tentou colocar um código legado para rodar com Java 12: a Oracle, agora, resolveu esconder de fato as implementações íntimas dela.

Não sei se você lembra, mas sabe os pacotes `sun.java.*`? Pois bem, eles eram pacotes internos que deveriam ser consumidos *apenas* pela JRE/JDK da Sun/Oracle. Em tese, nenhum programa feito para rodar em Java deveria depender desses pacotes. O que foi possível fazer com o Jigsaw? Removê-los do caminho =) Aí o que aconteceu com uma biblioteca legada que eu tinha que acessava `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`? Deu `ClassNotFoundException` e o sistema parou.

Sinceramente, eu achei ruim? Não, por incrível que pareça não achei ruim. Apenas curioso. Como o código a essa biblioteca foi perdido no espaço/tempo (e ela é um artefato depreciado), serviu apenas como mais um empurrão para abandoná-la.

Agora, como você obtém uma performance melhorada na busca pelo `classpath`?

Vamos voltar à classe que eu não tinha mais acesso, `sun.misc.Base64Encoder`. Quando se está em um módulo, a primeira busca será por classes daquele módulo. Então, no caso do módulo `java.base` (vamos fingir, ok? Não sei qual seria o módulo real), em dado momento foi necessário acessar à classe `sun.misc.Base64Encoder`. O processamento estava dentro do módulo `java.base`, então a primeira coisa que ele faz é inquirir *dentro do módulo* quem é `sun.misc.Base64Encoder` e ele encontra essa classe, pública.

Agora, estamos na minha implementação. Suponhamos que ela esteja devidamente portada para Java 9 e tenta acessar `sun.misc.Base64Encoder`. A primeira coisa que o `ClassLoader` tentará fazer será ver, dentro do módulo em que me situo, se tem alguma classe com essa assinatura. A resposta será não. Então, nesse momento, percorro também todos os outros módulos do `classpath` que declaro usar (ou herdo via `transitive`) e vejo se tem alguém que provê o pacote `sun.misc`, sem entrar neles profundamente para mais inspeções. Talvez uma ou outra biblioteca em Java 8- ofereça alguma resistência pois, por padrão, elas se comportam como se fossem módulos com todos os pacotes disponíveis.

Viu como o tempo de busca é reduzido usando módulos?

> Em termos de complexidade, o quão fácil é sua aplicabilidade em projetos grandes que já estão rodando em Java 8 por exemplo?

Você consegue modular bem o seu programa? Se sim, o primeiro passo será disponibilizar um `module-info.java` com as seguintes informações:

1. quais são os módulos que eu dependo? `requires`
2. para cada módulo requerido, devo deixar disponível para terceiros que importam do meu módulo ou não? `transitive`
3. quais pacotes vou expor programaticamente para que seja enxergado como parte do `classpath` para outros módulos? `exports`
4. quais classes gostaria que fosse acessível via `reflection`, mesmo que não esteja "disponível" para acessar diretamente pelo `ClassLoader´?`opens`

Esse passo do `opens` é o mais delicado quando se usa um framework que dependa bastante de `reflections` (como Spring, Hibernate, MyBatis etc).

Definindo tudo isso corretamente, e fazendo a separação adequada dos módulos, o resto devo fluir naturalmente. Eu particularmente vejo mais aplicação do Jigsaw para bibliotecas, mas não vi motivos para impedir de uma aplicação ser separada em módulos.

Agora, essas definições não são triviais de se fazer. Talvez uma reengenharia do código original para esconder a implementação movendo-a para outro pacote seja necessário.

> Durante atualização de bibliotecas, volta e meia nos deparamos com conflitos entre versões e dependências. Nesse cenário de modularização, este problema não se torna mais comum?

Uma vantagem que esse esquema fornece é poder ter diversas classes com o mesmo nome. O único requisito para isso é que elas não sejam de pacotes exportados. Uma biblioteca muito bem bolada possa conseguir fazer o uso adequado disso, mas a maioria é falta com `target` para Java 8.

Outro ponto é que isso não exime o gerenciamento de dependências pelo Maven ou Gradle (ou aquilo que você usa para este fim). Então, não vejo como o uso de módulos diminuiria esses problemas de atualização (com possível exceções de classes com a mesma assinatura em dois módulos distintos).

---

Referências:

- https://www.baeldung.com/project-jigsaw-java-modularity
- https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/